# python - is there a intelligent way for formatting strings with quotations?

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm using `neo4j` python lib to manipulate the neo4j graph database.

I need to format the cypher query like

```py
query = 'create (n:Person {{nickname: "{0}"}}) return n;'.format(nickname)
```

If the nickname contains a `"` itself like `A"B`, the generated query will be

`create (n:Person {nickname: "A"B"}) return n;` which will raise a syntax error in cql running.

In fact the cypher query language support `''` and `""` to indicate a string.

So my problem is, if there is a smart way, when the variable nickname contains `'` or `"`, the formatted string could automatically use the right quotation marks?

Comment: Query language used in combination with user input can lead to injection vulnerabilities. Usually there should be a function in the library to do safe quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `repr` function to format the string with proper quotation marks:

```
query = 'create (n:Person {{nickname: {0}}}) return n;'.format(repr(nickname))
```

since its behavior is exactly what you want, enclosing a given string with double quotes when the string contains a single quote, and single quotes when the string contains a double quote:

```
>>> print(repr("A'B"))
"A'B"
>>> print(repr('A"B'))
'A"B'
```

Comment: this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `"""Lorem ipsum"""` format string which allows you to use symbols and ascii chars. i.e

```
query = """create (n:Person {{nickname: "{0}"}}) return n;""".format(nickname)
```

> You could also use **single quotes** and **double qoutes** in the string.

Comment: that returns the same as what I wrote in the OP, the problem is I put the `"{0}"` in the original string. so it will always replace `{0}` with the variable.

Comment: Try this
```query = """create (n:Person {{nickname: {0}}}) return n;""".format(repr(nickname))```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is called "quotes escaping". The most simple way to do that is:

```
nickname='A"B'
query = 'create (n:Person {{nickname: "{0}"}}) return n;'.format(nickname.replace('"','\\"'))
print(query)

>>> 
create (n:Person {nickname: "A\"B"}) return n;
```

If you would like a more "formal" way, you can do following:

```
import json
person = {'nickname': 'A"B'}
query = 'create (n:Person {0}) return n;'.format(json.dumps(person))
print(query)
```

Comment: Your first method works, but the second won't work since the query will be `create (n:Person {"nickname": "A\\"B"}) return n`.

Comment: You are right, I overlooked it. The main idea was to use `json` module to handle the quote escaping.   Here the fix: `query = 'create (n:Person {{nickname: "{0}"}}) return n;'.format(json.dumps(nickname))` .